# how to automatically boot into a specific desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian

I try to use a script

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my Desktop setting
# Default-Start:     1 2 3 5 6
# Default-Stop:      
# Description:       Desktop setting
### END INIT INFO
mkdir /media/500g
mount /dev/sda1 /media/500g
d=0
 checkdisplay()
    {
    if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]; then 
    echo Display not set
    else
    d=111
fi
        return $d
    }
while [ $d != 111 ]
do
checkdisplay
done
pcmanfm --desktop
echo "pcmanfm desktop should run"
```

but the syslog says :

> my_basic.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.

when I test it from terminal the code works.

Comment: yes, the behavior of the script is exactly as you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

In the start-up scripts executed at boot time, the `DISPLAY` variable is never going to be set. Usually either the X display manager (`gdm`, `sddm`, `xdm` or some other `*dm`) or the `startx` command will start the X server and set up the GUI session, and only those processes and their children will have the `DISPLAY` variable set.

When a new process is started, its parent process will give it a set of environment variables (like `DISPLAY`). Usually it's just a copy of the set of environment variables given to the parent process by the grandparent, but if necessary, the parent process can modify the variables before passing them on. After the process is started, the parent process can no longer change the environment variables of the child process in any way: the child and parent will both have their own set of environment variables that are fully separate from each other.

So your `checkdisplay()` test makes no sense: if the `DISPLAY` variable was not set when your script was started, it is not going to become set while your script is running, unless your script will deliberately change it.

It seems to me that your script should not be placed as a system start-up script, but instead as a X11 session start-up script. If you're using Ubuntu/Debian, `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` might be the right place if you want this script to run for all users; if you want it to run for one particular user only, then it will depend on which desktop environment or window manager you're using: placing your script in `~/.config/autostart-scripts` might be the solution if your desktop conforms to the relatively recent Freedesktop.org standards.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days searching and testing I found the best solution which works. The problem was that the desktop has to be arranged after finishing boot -in my case after `xorg.service` .

The steps were the following :

1. I created two files "my_desktop.service" and "my_desktop"

The file "my_desktop.service" is placed in `/etc/systemd/system` and contains code:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Desktop
After=xorg.service

[Service]
Type=idle
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my_desktop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The file "my_desktop" is placed in `/usr/local/bin/` and has code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Description:       Desktop setting
export DISPLAY=:0.0
pcmanfm --desktop
```

2. I activated the service above via terminal (one by one) in order :

```
systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl enable my_desktop.service

systemctl start my_desktop.service
```

...and now my desktop works smoothly

So my script had to be used as an after boot service.